# Merge Sort time complexity analysis

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, sorting

How can I prove that $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$ is $O(n \log n)$ ?

Comment: The more interesting question is: How do you come up with the hypothesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ideas to do this. The first one is telescoping where you recursively use the definition of $T(n)$ or you could of course use induction (this almost always works). For a sketch of the proof check page 3 [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr07/cos226/lectures/04MergeQuick.pdf). Note that here it is assumed that $n$ is a power of 2 making the proof simpler, if not it goes in the same fashion nevertheless.

Comment: @Dan If, for some reason, you could solve the recurrence for $n$ a power of two, but couldn't solve it for a general $n$, then you can do the following. Let $n'$ be the power of two such that $n \leq n' < 2n$. Then $T(n) \leq T(n') = O(n' \log n') = O(2n \log (2n)) = O(n \log n)$. The constant hidden by the $O$ notation is slightly worse, but that's fine.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Use induction to show that there are constants $c$ and $n_0$ s.t. $T(n) \leq c \cdot n \log n \quad\forall n \geq n_0$. Use $T(2)$ as your base case. Remember cool log properties to reduce the logarithm and to use the induction hypothesis.

Post your progress if you get stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Let $L(k)=T(2^k)$ and $n = 2^k$.  Then $L(k)=T(n)$, $L(k-1)=T(n/2)$, and thus,
$$
L(k)=2L(k-1)+2^k\tag1
$$
Multiplying $(1)$ by $2^{-k}$ gives
$$
\overbrace{2^{-k}L(k)}^{a_k}=\overbrace{2^{-(k-1)}L(k-1)}^{a_{k-1}}+1\tag2
$$
Iterating $(2)$, we get
$$
2^{-k}L(k)=L(0)+k\tag3
$$
which means
$$
L(k)=2^k(L(0)+k)\tag4
$$
which is
$$
T(n)=n(T(1)+\log(n))\tag5
$$
Therefore, $T(n)=O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: This is how you come up with the hypothesis, not a proof.

Comment: @Raphael: Above, it is shown that $L(k)=2^kL(0)+k\;2^k$. That is, $L(k)=O(k2^k)$. Unfortunately, the hypothesis only allows us to compute $T(n)$ for $n=m2^k$, for some $m$. The argument above works for any $m$ (I chose $m=1$, but for a different $m$, only the big-O constant needs to be adjusted). Therefore, the result above for $n=2^k$ is essentially all we can infer. Hopefully, there are some other assumptions, such as monotonicity, which can be used to extend the estimate above to all values of $n$.

Comment: @Raphael: Perhaps you are worried about the free-form induction. Sometimes free-form induction is easier to follow, and gets the idea across more clearly. The point of a proof is to convince the reader that the statement being proven is true, and I hope that that is accomplished above.

Comment: That is indeed my problem with such "proofs". The expressiveness of $\dots$ heavily depends on the reader. Also, they can be "used" to hide bugs. In this particular case, an induction is probably even shorter than your pattern-guessing steps; of course, you'd need both.

Comment: @Raphael: I finally got brought back to this answer (9 years later). I've rewritten the iteration so it is easier to follow (without ellipses). It says the same thing, but hopefully in a more palatable manner.

Answer (score 4):

T(1) = 1

T(n) = 2T (n/2) + cn

T(n) = 2T (n/2) + cn

T(n/2) = 2T(n/4) + c (n/2)

T(n) = 2 [ 2T (n/4) + c (n/2) ] + cn

T(n) = 4T (n/4) + 2cn

Similary, 
T(n) = 8T (n/8) + 3cn

General 
T(n) = 2^k T (n/2^K) + kcn

(n/2^k) = 1

n = 2^k

k = log base2 n

plug in k into the general formula

T(n) = n T(1) + logBase2n cn

T(n) = Big Thetha(n log n )

Comment: nice analysis ....thanks

Comment: NB: `b^(logBase(b) x) = x ` note when substituting k into the general formula

Answer (score 1):

Use the  [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).